# JavaScript, Set up event in a calendar

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me please with this?

So I have two text boxes, one for the day of the month, one for the actual text(event title). Then there is a button to run the code and place the event. This should overwrite whatever had previously been the event for that day.
I was trying to write a function for it, but it didn't work.
I have dayEvent for every day in a month.

```html
<p>Enter a day: <input type="text" id="enter_day" /></p>
<p>Enter an event: <input type="text" id="enter_day" /></p>
<input type="button" onclick="myEvent()" value="Click here" />
```

```js
var dayEvent = new Array();

function myEvent() {
  var newEvent = document.getElementById('enter_day').value;
  var dayForEvent = document.getElementById('enter_day').value;
  dayEvent[dayForEvent] = newEvent;
}

dayEvent[1] =
  "<br /><a href='#'>Giveaway with Cesar Millan</a><br />12 am <br />online";
dayEvent[2] =
  "<br /><a href='#'>Classic Cinema: Wings</a><br />7 pm <br />at AMC Empire 25";
```

Comment: Both inputs have the ID `enter_day`. Is that a typo in this question or a mistake in you code?

Comment: Hey Nastya, did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: Glad I could help :) Would you be so kind to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the big gray check button on its left side?

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the duplicate ID problem fixes your code:

```js
var dayEvent = [
  "<br/><a href='#'>Giveaway with Cesar Millan</a><br/>12 am <br/>online",
  "<br/><a href='#'>Classic Cinema: Wings</a><br/>7 pm <br/>at AMC Empire 25"
];

function myEvent() {
  var newEvent = document.getElementById('enter_event').value;
  var dayForEvent = document.getElementById('enter_day').value;
  dayEvent[dayForEvent] = newEvent;
  
  console.info("Array after change: ", dayEvent)
}


console.info("Array before change: ", dayEvent)
```

```html
<p>Enter a day: <input type="text" id="enter_day" /></p>
<p>Enter an event: <input type="text" id="enter_event" /></p>
<input type="button" onclick="myEvent()" value="Click here" />
```

Note that I changed your code to use the literal array declaration syntax with square brackets.

Next, remember that array indices start with `0`, not `1`.

Finally, I would suggest that you use an input with `type="number"` for the day input, or do some validation yourself with `parseInt()` or such.